# Reading in text document as array in C and giving each line an ID

Tags: c, arrays, string

I was assigned to read in a text file in which there is one word on every line. I then have to reference these words with numbers based on their order. I need to make an array of strings but from what I understand it is not that simple. I am able to read in the file and run through each line using fscanf, just need help with putting each line in an array.

Comment: Fairly broad.  Maybe post code of what you have tried with "... just need help with putting each line in an array."

Comment: Find out about the `strdup()` function.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand out of your quite ambiguous question, you are looking for something like this:

```
void read_lines(void)
{
    // Load/Open your input file.
    File *file;
    file = fopen("yourfile.txt", "r");
    // Check if the file was opened correctly.
    if(!file){
        printf("Failed to load file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // This buffer will hold the individual lines/words. You may adapt its size.
    char *lines[100];
    // Loop through the entire length of the buffer.
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        // Allocate space in the buffer, before reading the line.
        lines[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
        // Check if malloc gave you a valid pointer.
        if(!lines[i]){
            printf("Memory allocation failed.\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        // Read everything up to the \n character in to the buffer.
        if(fscanf(file, "%99[^\n]\n", lines[i]) == 0){
            // If we encountered the end of the file, 
            // free the last buffer location again and break out of the loop.
            free(lines[i]);
            lines[i] = NULL;
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

This way you would have an array `lines` containing the contents of each line in your file in a new array-position. You may now index those lines however you whish.

---

EDIT: If you want to assign a unique custom ID to each line, you can of course create a struct

```
struct line_with_id {
    int id;
    char *line;
};
```

and make an array of structs instead of an array to char-pointers, if this is what you wanted. Adapting the above code to account for this should be fairly straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple implementation to read a file (one word per-line) into an array of characters is to declare a static array of sufficient size to hold the words read from the file. You can declare the character array as a 2D array where each row in the array will hold one word. Unless you have special needs, all words in the abridged dictionary are *28 characters* or less. (adjust to any length you need to accommodate your data) You must add an additional character to hold the *nul-terminating* character required at the end of every valid string.

While you can trivially read each line with `fscanf`, the general approach to reading one-line-at-a-time is to use the *line-oriented* input functions provided by the standard library (e.g. `fgets` or `getline`). The following is a short example of reading words from a file into an array. The program expects the filename to be passed as the first argument.

**note:** A simple `ternary` operator is used to allow the program to read from `stdin` (by default) if no filename is given. The ternary operator simply has the form `"(test condition) ? (if true action) : (if false action)"` (without the `()` being required). So the statement you see declaring the `FILE` pointer `fp`:

```
FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
```

simply says *test* `argc > 1`. If that is true (e.g. at least 1 argument was given), then `fopen (argv[1], "r")`. If the *test* is not true, then simply use `stdin`. It is just a handy way to provide a *default* here (or an alternate value - generally) .

The rest of the example should be straight forward.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXW 64  /* maximum number of lines to read */
#define MAXC 32  /* longest word in abridged Dict. is 28 char 
                    "Antidisestablishmentarianism"  */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char words [MAXW][MAXC] = {{0}};    /* array to hold words */
    size_t idx = 0;                     /* index of words read */
    size_t i;

    /* open argv[1] for reading (default: stdin) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* read each line in file into words array 
       note: includes trailing newline character */
    while (fgets (words[idx], MAXC, fp)) {
        idx++;
        if (idx == MAXW) {  /* check word count against MAXW */
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: MAXW words read.\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file */

    printf ("\n words read from '%s':\n\n", 
            argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "stdin");
    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)
        printf ("  words[%2zu] : %s", i, words[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Input File**

```
$ cat dat/captnjack1.txt
This
is
a
tale
Of
Captain
Jack
Sparrow
A
Pirate
So
Brave
On
the
Seven
Seas.
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/fgets_array_words dat/captnjack1.txt

 words read from 'dat/captnjack1.txt':

  words[ 0] : This
  words[ 1] : is
  words[ 2] : a
  words[ 3] : tale
  words[ 4] : Of
  words[ 5] : Captain
  words[ 6] : Jack
  words[ 7] : Sparrow
  words[ 8] : A
  words[ 9] : Pirate
  words[10] : So
  words[11] : Brave
  words[12] : On
  words[13] : the
  words[14] : Seven
  words[15] : Seas.
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

**note:** reading from `stdin`, the output would be identical except for the referenced filename. e.g.:

```
$ ./bin/fgets_array_words <dat/captnjack1.txt

 words read from 'stdin':

  words[ 0] : This
  words[ 1] : is
  ...
```